# Opening OneNote Online notebook on Mac attempts to open in VMWare

Tags: macos, onenote, vmware-fusion

When I'm on my mac and viewing a OneNote notebook via SharePoint, I click the "Open in OneNote" link/Button, and my mac attempts to open the Notebook using the OneNote installed on my Virtual machine (VMWare Fusion). I can't figure out how to get it to use the one on my Mac instead. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this [link](https://pubs.vmware.com/fusion-6/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.fusion.help.doc%2FGUID-7C24F5D6-D224-42B1-B5E1-9171AC0A8F91.html)
It looks like you need the select the following option
**Open your Windows files and web links using Mac applications**